# Search and replace in text file - add a constant to a numbered sequence

Tags: batch-file, replace

I've got a file, actually a .bat file but it could be any text file, with contents I want to update. I want to replace throughout the file the number after some text like this:

`%varXX` where *XX* is a number, one or two digits. The numbers go typically from 1 to 35.

Example: `%var10` ---> add a known number to add to 10, like 2, result is `%var12`. I want to choose the number I start doing this at like 10 in this example and I want to choose the number to add to all of these occurrences, up to 35 occurrences. I will also need to, at times, subtract instead of add this number. I'm on a windows computer.

Update - found part solution using VIM:

```
:%s@%var\(\d\+\)@\='%var' . (submatch(1) + 3)@g
```

Here in this example, `3` is the amount I'm adding. However, this searches for any numbers following `var` and adds `3`. How do I modify the above command to start at a number I choose?